# Iron Router Package issue in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I need to know about the usage of iron router packae.I am using the latest version of meteor.

**Issue** : i am using **Router.go('hello');**

Router.go working fine.But the problem is **append to the `hello`template  data to the already existing one.**

Please see the below code :

router.js :

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.route('hello',{path: 'hello'});
});
```

hello.html:

```
<Template name = "hello">
   <h1>This is hello sections</h1>
</Template>
```

sampleApp.Html:

```
<head>
  <title>sampleApp</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello1}}
</body>

<template name="hello1">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

sample.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello1.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to sampleApp.";
  };

  Template.hello1.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
        Router.go('hello');
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Output Displays :

Before Button Click :

```
Hello World!
Welcome to sampleApp.
**Button Click Me**
```

After Button Click :

```
Hello World!
Welcome to sampleApp.
**Button Click Me**
This is hello sections
```

Here the problem is Route.go not goes to new page.SO how to do.Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just remove the section:
`<body> {{>hello1}} </body>` and it will work as you want it to :) The stuff inside the body tag will always be rendered.

Comment: did you try this and did it work? Please mark as correct if so. Thanks!